# Описание полей класса ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Скажите пожалуйста является ли правильной практикой описания внутренних полей класса (ES6) и функций замыкания следующим образом:

```
class A {
    a = 1;

    print = () => {
       console.log(this.a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

С точки зрения [и 6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-method-definitions), [и 7](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-ClassBody) версий спецификации

Тело класса имеет следующую структуру

```
ClassBody[Yield] :  
    ClassElementList[?Yield]

ClassElementList[Yield] :
    ClassElement[?Yield]
    ClassElementList[?Yield] ClassElement[?Yield]

ClassElement[Yield]:
    MethodDefinition[?Yield]
    static MethodDefinition[?Yield]
    ;
```

В свою очередь [MethodDefinition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-method-definitions) имеет вид

```
MethodDefinition[Yield] :
    PropertyName[?Yield] ( StrictFormalParameters ) { FunctionBody }
    GeneratorMethod[?Yield]
    get PropertyName[?Yield] ( ) { FunctionBody }
    set PropertyName[?Yield] ( PropertySetParameterList ) { FunctionBody }
```

Как можно заметить, в теле класса разрешено только определение функций, без использования оператора присваивания, и код в вопросе должен вызывать ошибку синтаксиса.

Поэтому на вопрос

> является ли правильной практикой описания внутренних полей класса (ES6)

Можно однозначно ответить: **нет**, с точки зрения спецификации - данный код даже не должен выполняться.

С другой стороны, с точки зрения, например, TypeScript, такие объявления вполне имееют место быть.

Answer (score 3):

На данный момент мне не известно чтобы спецификация поддерживала объявление свойств в теле класса. Но я слышал что это будет в следующих версиях, а пока эту возможность можно реализовать с использованием `babel`.

Является ли это правильным? Да, является! Компилятор за Вас соберет эти свойства и запишет их в конструктор. Поэтому если Вам так удобней читать код, то пишите.

Так же хочется сказать пару слов о `get/set` упомянутые ранее.. Аксессоры стоит применять только в тех случаях, когда они возвращают не объект по прямой ссылке. То есть если у Вас есть свойство `this._object` и Вы хотите вернуть его через геттер `get object() { return this._object; }`, то это будет аморально и бессмысленно (если Вы конечно не хотите в при изменении вызвать что-то), так как суть геттеров ограничивать доступ к объекту, а в данном случаи Вы целиком отдаете объект и кто угодно сможет сделать с ним что угодно. Цель аксессоров примерно в этом `get object() { return this._object.props; }`.