# Как декларируется state через знак "равно" в компоненте React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, классы, ecmascript-6

Допустим есть компонент **Header** у которого будет объявлен **state**:

```
class Header extends React.Component {
  state = {someValue: '1'}
}
```

**Как декларируется state через знак "равно" в компоненте React?**

Как это возможно, если после конструктора можно объявлять только методы?

*Заранее спасибо за ответы.*

Comment: `ReactDOM.render(<Main />, node);` тоже неправильно, но работает, смекаешь суть?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Это аргумент, но хотелось бы знать возможно ли это сделать каким-то способом самому. Вот прям очень интересно

Comment: @AleksySzugało, без препроцессора - нет. Спецификация разрешает объявлять только методы и конструктор внутри тела класса

Comment: Спасибо большое! Теперь всё стало на свои места

Comment: @AleksySzugało, немного [спецификации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599113/186999)

Comment: @Grundy, Кто о чём, а Grundy о спецификациях.

Comment: @Other, спецификация всему голова! Сделал дело - прочти спецификацию! Семь раз отмерь, один - прочти спецификацию!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @AleksySzugało, без препроцессора - нет. Спецификация разрешает
>   объявлять только методы и конструктор внутри тела класса – [Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy)

**Такой код может быть выполнен только при помощи препроцессора**