# Почему в новом объекте появляется свойство не из конструктора js

Tags: javascript, классы

```js
    class Hamburger{
      meat = 0;
      constructor(type) {
        this.type = type;
      }
    }
    let myHmburger = new Hamburger('classic')
    myHmburger.meat // 0
```

Почему в новом объекте вдруг появилось свойство meat, я ведь не в конструкторе его писал. Как тогда этот код выглядел бы не в es6?

Comment: формально данный код в es6,7,8,9,10 приводил бы к синтаксической ошибке.

Answer (score 2):

Хотя формально, также как и раньше, в [спецификации нет описания полей класса](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#prod-ClassElement), только методов (подробнее в ответе на вопрос: [Описание полей класса ES6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599113/186999)), браузеры могут реализовывать описание полей на свое усмотрение.

Например Chrome, помещает описанное поле непосредственно в объект, как будто его объявили в конструкторе через `this`

```
class Hamburger{
  meat = 0;
  constructor(type) {
    this.type = type;
  }
}
```

то же, что и

```
class Hamburger{
  constructor(type) {
    this.meat = 0;
    this.type = type;
  }
}
```

однако другие браузеры могут либо упасть с ошибкой синтаксиса, либо поместить указанное поле в прототип.

Comment: спасибо, ни в жизнь бы не дошел бы, что тут дело в браузере, а код вообще не стоит использовать такой